# The invocation of the constructor on type 'ReportDesigner' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception

Tags: wpf, syncfusion

I'm using the Syncfusion Report designer tool, when I run the application, this exception is thrown:
message:

> Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an
>   exception

inner exception:

> The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'Syncfusion.Windows.Reports.Designer.ReportDesigner' that matches the
>   specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '112'
>   and line position '14'."}

stack trace:

> at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst,
>   XamlMember property, Object value)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.SetValue(Object
>   obj, XamlMember property, Object value)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx, XamlMember prop, Object value, Boolean onParent)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx)    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter
>   xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter
>   xamlWriter)    at
>   System.Windows.SystemResources.ResourceDictionaries.LoadDictionary(Assembly
>   assembly, String assemblyName, String resourceName, Boolean
>   isTraceEnabled)    at
>   System.Windows.SystemResources.ResourceDictionaries.LoadGenericDictionary(Boolean
>   isTraceEnabled)    at
>   System.Windows.SystemResources.FindDictionaryResource(Object key, Type
>   typeKey, ResourceKey resourceKey, Boolean isTraceEnabled, Boolean
>   allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean
>   mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, Boolean& canCache)    at
>   System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key,
>   Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean
>   mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(FrameworkElement fe,
>   FrameworkContentElement fce)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnThemeStyleKeyChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_DefaultStyleKey(Object value)
>   at Syncfusion.Windows.Reports.Designer.ReportDesigner..ctor()

this all I can get, I can't figure out what is the exact problem!

Comment: My crystal ball says it's the gardener. It's always the gardener!

Comment: What is this ???

Answer (score 0):

Based on stack trace, it may occurred due to the framework version or due to the internal binding with report designer. You can check this query with Syncfusion support,
https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/wpf/reportdesigner